# Is there any John Williams-derived music in "The Mandalorian"?

Tags: star-wars, soundtrack, the-mandalorian

When I watched *The Mandalorian*, I was pleasantly surprised that the show had chosen to go its own way musically, with a very unique sound for its main theme, rather than only borrow from and build on John Williams' original work as so much of *Star Wars* media does.

However, given that *Star Wars* as a franchise has a strong track record of musical consistency (using and re-using musical themes and motifs between movies and TV episodes), I would have thought that least some recognizable themes would pop up at specific points - in [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxrUuXpdVTg), for instance, I fully expected to hear "Binary Sunset" (which would traditionally accompany such a Force power reveal), and found its absence almost jarring.

In fact, I couldn't identify a single piece of music in *The Mandalorian* which I was familiar with from previous *Star Wars* media. Are there really none, or did I miss some somewhere?

Comment: It's a bit subjective, but the music from that scene sounds a lot like the Force Theme with some notes removed or rearranged to me. I don't know enough about music theory to say if it's related to it in some objective sense, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is!

Watch the scenes featuring the two New Republic pilots: first in **Chapter 9**, when the two rescue Mando from ice spiders, then in **Chapter 12**, when Carson Teva gives Cara Dune with his medal. In both scenes, the score is a slowed-down, melodramatic cover of John Williams' 'March of the Resistance' from the sequel trilogy.

Here it is on the Mandalorian soundtrack:

Answer (score 5):

Another instance appears in **Chapter 13**, at 19:53, when

> Ahsoka recalls Master Yoda. Yoda's theme briefly begins to play.

You can hear it at about 2:00 here:

Answer (score 0):

There's likely to be some incidental music from John Williams to retain continuity with the older series but most of the music is by the Swedish composer, Ludwig Gorannson, who is following in John Williams footsteps, as far as the music goes.